# What does the combination of や and もmean?

Tags: particles

I don't understand the following sentence:

> やさい や くだもの も おおい です。

I know that や is used for incomplete enumeration and も means "also". But how to interpret such a combination of these two particles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of the particles as used are correct.

Depending on context, it seems like this sentence could be a direct response to another.

**Original statement**

> 肉{にく}や魚{さかな}も多い{おおい}です。
>
> *There are a lot of meat and fish.*

**Response statement**

> 野菜{やさい}や果物{くだもの}も多{おお}いです
>
> *There are **also** many vegetables and fruits*.

Comment: Ah yes, the previous sentence is あたらしい さかな が おおい です. In that case does the sentence mean "There are also a lot of vegetables and fruit (among other things which are a lot of)"? I am curious about the や particle.

Comment: Correct, if や was replaced with と it would be a exhaustive list. 'There are also a lot of vegetables and fruit' (and nothing more)